# RunJar running multiple times in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I stopped all node by typing `sh stop-all.sh` Now When I am typing jps command it is giving the following result.

[image]

Why RunJar is running multiple times. Another thing I want to write here is that I installed Pig yesterday, may be its not related to that?

Comment: Are you running any jar manually or by some othrway??

Comment: I don't think so i started it manually , is there any specific command to stop RunJar in terminal.

Comment: Kill all the process.kill -9 4074 ...